C++ Winsock and Qt threading
The execution of the server code reaches the accept() function, and the GUI thread takes control, it is very important to me that the acceptSocket is structured because by calling SendMessage() program terminates. WSAGetLastError() returns error #10038. What am I supposed to do?
void Tcp_server::init(int amount_of_connections){
    int wsaerr;
    std::mutex mut;
    WORD wVersionRequired = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequired, &wsaData);
    try {
        if (wsaerr != 0) {
            throw WSAGetLastError();
        }
        std::cout << "The winsock dll is found!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The status: " << wsaData.szSystemStatus << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            throw WSAGetLastError();
        }
        std::cout << "socket() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "socket() failed, Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    std::string m_address = "192.168.0.103";

    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, m_address.c_str(), &service.sin_addr.s_addr);
    service.sin_port = htons(8080);
    try {
        if (bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            throw WSAGetLastError();
        }
        std::cout << "bind() is OK!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "bind() failed, Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex>l(mut);
    if (listen(serverSocket, amount_of_connections) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Listening error# " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    else {
        std::cout << "listen() is OK, waiting for connections..." << std::endl;
    }
    acceptSocket = accept(serverSocket,NULL,NULL);
    if (acceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cout << "accept() failed, ERROR# " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        exit(-1);
    }
}

mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "ServerClass.h"
#include<thread>
Tcp_server server(1);
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    std::thread session(server.init,server,1);
    session.join();
    ui->setupUi(this);



}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_Connect_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_Send_clicked()
{

    QString mess_text = ui->Message->text();
    ui->textBrowser->append(mess_text);

    server.SendMessage(mess_text,server.getaccSocket());
    ui->Message->clear();

}






I tried to lock the accept() with std::mutex. It didn't work. Also i tried to use join() function rather than detach() It didn't work too. The program just stops executing

creating a thread and immediately joining it is somewhat pointless. There is no concurrency in doing so. Its like "start a thread, it should do something seperate from the current thread" and immediately after "now make the current thread wait for it to finish"

No matter where I am joining the session thread, program just stops responding  Maybe there are concurrent analog of accept() function?

While debugging, code stops responding on accept() call therefore acceptSocket == SOCKET_ERROR

No, this i my problem. I can't figure out how to make accept() function finish the work

You are calling accept() on a server socket that is operating in blocking mode, so it will block the calling code until a client connects.  If you do not want accept() to block your code, then call it in a separate thread of its own after listen() has opened the port. Or else put the socket into non-blocking mode and run accept inside your message loop. Or, since you are using a UI window, consider using WSAAsyncSelect() instead. Also, your exception handling is useless

Thanks. Really appreciate it. Now I at least have a direction to move

However, since the thread subject line also mentions Qt -- does Qt really not give you any kind of lowish-level networking support?

Yes, but I am practicing Winsock and I thought that it would be simple to do a primitive GUI on Qt

Well, I solved the proglem. Big thanks to Remy
